# Is Origin the common agreed name for protocol + hostname (+ port)?

Tags: url

Is Origin the common agreed name for protocol + hostname (+ port)?

I know it is in JavaScript (not supported in IE), but I can't really find the word Origin back in other sources on the internet.

Is there an official name for this part of the url?

Explanation: 
It's for naming a database column, and while HostName makes pretty clear what it is, I'm affraid the column name Origin wouldn't be as clear.

But if it's the common agreed word then I think it's the best name - just want to be sure it's not some really specific JavaScript only term.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it counts a "commonly" used term or not, but in Microsoft terminology the scheme + host name + port number is referred to as the URL "Authority". See MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority.aspx

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142910/whats-the-difference-between-uri-host-and-uri-authority

There seems to be a hint in the w3c HTML5 spec that this may be a valid use of the term "authority" in that an *authoritative URL* is one in which the scheme (like HTTPS) is followed by two slashes "//" with the part following the double slashes being the host. So it may be valid for Microsoft to refer to the URL's authority as being something like: "https://www.example.com:8080" in the example "https://www.example.com.8080/an-example-of-an-absolute-url.html"

See https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/urls.html#authority-based-url

Comment: Hi @dthrasher, thanks for your answer. Authority seems to just return the hostname + port, and not the scheme :/ See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority(v=vs.110).aspx